# "Believe in an afterlife" or "believe in the afterlife"?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Could you tell which article I use after *afterlife*: *an* or *the*? For example:

> Do you believe in **an** afterlife?
>
> Do you believe in **the** afterlife?

I have seen both used before *afterlife*, but I can't figure out the logic of using one but not the other. Is it just a matter of style?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You likely know how the definite article works in comparison to the indefinite article. If there is only one of something we use the definite article.

With this question of *belief*, the choice of article really reflects what the person asking the question knows, believes, or assumes about the person they are posing the question to. There are many different beliefs about an afterlife, but if a person believes one then they likely discount the others.

So, if someone asked "do you believe in **the** afterlife?" that would imply that the person asking the question either believes there is only one, or is only aware of one that can be believed in.

If someone asked "do you believe in **an** afterlife?" that would imply that the person asking the question is aware that there is more than one possible belief about an afterlife.

Comment: Use of _the_ could be **generic**, too; i.e. recognizing that there are different beliefs, but they're assumed to be similar enough to be part of the same meme of "afterlifism". Similar to "are you taking _the_ train?", "Did you ride _the_ bus?": the person asking doesn't care which train or bus.

Comment: "*the* afterlife? [IME] that would imply that the person asking the question [is a Christian who adheres to the second commandment: *Thou shalt have no other gods before me.*]"

Comment: @rich that's a possibility, but the OP is looking to make a conscious choice between them.

Comment: @Mazura I can't really agree with that. The scripture you quote is about monotheism, believing in only one god, not one afterlife. There are polytheistic religions that believe in many gods but only one afterlife. Also, a Christian is far more likely to say "heaven" than "afterlife".

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

Absence of the article "the" indicates that you are not talking about any particular afterlife.

Presence of the article "the" indicates that you are talking about a particular afterlife that you have already mentioned previously.

For example:

(*starting conversation*) Hello, do you believe in an afterlife? -- You have never defined an afterlife yet, hence no article.

(*or*) The Bible talks about life after death where good guys go to heaven and bad ones go to hell. Do you believe in **the** afterlife? -- This suggests that you are talking about about this particular afterlife, not some totally different (for example Viking) afterlife.

It is worth noting that article "the" relates to "this". In a way, when you say "the object" you are saying "this object (that I have mentioned before)". Also, "a" / "an" relates to "any", thus saying "an object" means "any object (pick one to your liking)".

Comment: It is grammatically incorrect, I believe, in American English not to use an article here (either 'the' or 'an')

Comment: I agree with Matthew. A zero determiner to indicate an indefinite concept or category is usually only done in the plural, or with mass/uncountable nouns. In the singular, we use "a" or "an."

Comment: @MatthewBarclay Thank you, I edited the answer